# OpenLayers Draw modules in React components doesn't update the map

Tags: reactjs, openlayers-5

I'm working on an OpenLayers map that uses React as a wrapper for all the other UI stuff. As such, I'm also trying to component-ize some of the features, in this case the drawing.

Below is an attempt to recreate the example found in the [OpenLayers documentation](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/draw-features.html). What happens is that I get the draw surface, it does the drawing, but then once the drawing has been completed, nothing shows on the map.

I also have a living example of the behavior in a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/l3jz05lll).

**MapComponent**

```
import React, { Component, createRef } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Map from "ol/Map";
import View from "ol/View";
import OSM from "ol/source/OSM";
import TileLayer from "ol/layer/Tile";
import DrawingComponent from "./DrawingComponent";

class MapComponent extends Component {
  mapDomRef;
  map;

  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
    this.mapDomRef = createRef();
    this.map = new Map();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const view = new View({
      center: [-11000000, 4600000],
      zoom: 4
    });

    const rasterLayer = new TileLayer({
      source: new OSM()
    });

    this.map.addLayer(rasterLayer);
    this.map.setTarget(this.mapDomRef.current);
    this.map.setView(view);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div ref={this.mapDomRef} />

        <DrawingComponent map={this.map} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**DrawingComponent**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Draw from "ol/interaction/Draw";
import { Vector as VectorSource } from "ol/source";
import { Vector as VectorLayer } from "ol/layer";

class DrawingComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    geomType: "None"
  };

  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
    this.source = new VectorSource({ wrapX: false });
    this.layer = new VectorLayer({ source: this.source });
  }

  handleGeomChange = event => {
    const geomType = event.target.value;
    this.setState(({ draw }) => {
      if (draw) {
        this.props.map.removeInteraction(draw);
      }

      return { geomType, draw: this.addInteraction(geomType) };
    });
  };

  addInteraction(geomType) {
    if (geomType !== "None") {
      const draw = new Draw({
        source: this.source,
        type: geomType
      });

      this.props.map.addInteraction(draw);
      return draw;
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form class="form-inline">
        <label>Geometry type &nbsp;</label>
        <select
          id="type"
          value={this.state.geomType}
          onChange={this.handleGeomChange}
        >
          <option value="Point">Point</option>
          <option value="LineString">LineString</option>
          <option value="Polygon">Polygon</option>
          <option value="Circle">Circle</option>
          <option value="None">None</option>
        </select>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default DrawingComponent;
```

EDIT: Applied suggestion to use the same source that's on the map, which meant, to also add the layer, which I wasn't doing before.

Comment: To update the map the source for an interaction must also be the source for a layer on the map.

Comment: Ah. So they have to be the same sources! Doh! 

Comment: I've updated it to use the same source. I also added the layer, which I apparently wasn't doing either, but the problem is still there.

Comment: @jktravis did you figure this out?  I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @JDun The only way I've been able to make this stuff work is through context. It seems that sending the map through as a prop is problematic for some reason.

Comment: @jktravis, did you solved this? I have the same issue

Comment: @RafaelBarbosa I don’t recall exactly. I think I may have switched to using the context API instead of passing the prop.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have added the vector layer before the raster layer.  If you add the vector layer first, the raster layer will render over top of the vectors.

Comment: The only thing that has ever seemed to work is passing the map through the React's context API. Props just don't seem to do it.